# Does it matter where is live and where is neutral when wiring an electronic ballast?

Tags: wiring, lamp

I just bought a new electronic ballast to replace the old one for my florescent lamp. However, the connection diagram on the ballast does not indicate where I should connect the live and neutral wires. There are also no L and N markings on either side.

[image: Loyal Electronic Ballast 40W]

Does it matter at all or am I putting myself at risk of a shock if connected wrongly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no indication whatsoever then no, it doesn't matter.

That looks like an internationally universal ballast, so in the US you'd have two hots @ 240V/60Hz, and in a place like the UK you'd have a hot and a neutral @ 230V/50Hz.

Answer (score 1):

Are you in the USA? If so, then you won't have a neutral because it requires 230 volts.